# If one cell (in a range) = "X" and another cell (in a range) ="Y" then add 1. What is the correct formula to use for this.

Tags: google-sheets

If one cell (in a range) = "X" and another cell (in a range) ="Y" then add 1. What is the correct formula to use for this. I've tried IF, IF AND, IF THEN, and just AND. Keep getting error.

Comment: Can you please share the formula you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

AND: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301

```
=AND(logical_expression1, [logical_expression2, ...])
```

IF: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364

```
=IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

AND tests multiple arguments for logical true, so you need to use that function inside of the IF function for it's logical_expression like so:

```
=IF(AND(logical_expression1, logical_expression2), value_if_true, value_if_false)
```